# App won't start for button-onclick code

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I make a simple app which has 7 activities , 2 high quality background images [I created drawable-xxhdpi folder and paste all background images there all background images there including button images]

Also I created assets folder folder as I want to show HTML file on button click

Problem - when I am running the app the app is automatically crashing. the app won't  start. after removing the button-onclick code I try again and the app is working ,but cannot go to another activity.

I think the problem is happening for button onclick-code .I cannot go to go to other activity on button click

Here is  activity main.xml file photo and also the mainactivity.java file photo

Java file photo - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKmUr.jpg

Xml file photo - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZiEu.jpg

Also, here is a detailed video regarding this problem check it out

Link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KLhK9gQ_ejILN-gwPZ42G_BpfgZKQSKk/view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start another activity using **action name** of another activity in your **mainfest file**.

```
Intent i = new Intent("Action name defined for second activity in android mainfest under application");
```

Comment: No..tell me in details